# Slide toggle Jquery sometimes gets stuck I have no idea why

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi basically I have a element when I hover over it I have a div that slides up from the bottom and when I stop hovering over the element the div slides back down.

Currently I have it working, however on odd occasions the div that slides up and down gets stuck and the sliding up and down is reversed and I have no idea why. By reversed I mean when I'm not hovering the div element is shown and then when I hover it slides down.

The only way which makes the element stop doing that at the moment is by refreshing.

can any one guide me in solving this issue?

Many thanks

Code: 
JAVA SCRIPT

```
      $(document).ready(function () 
       {
        $("div.small_info_container").hover(function () 
        {  
          $(this).parent().find('div.small_slide_info_container').slideToggle("fast");
        });
      });
```

CSS:

```
.elem {
width: 248px;
height: 238px;
margin: 10px 0 0 5px;
float: left;
border: 1px solid #ACACAC;
background: white;
box-shadow: 3px 4px 2px -2px #CACACA;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;

}

.small_info_container {
position: absolute;
width: 248px;
height: 238px;
background:transparent;
}

.small_slide_info_container {
position: absolute;
width: 248px;
height: 45px;
background: rgba(173, 173, 173, 0.36);
display: none;
bottom: 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="elem">
    <div class="small_info_container">
        <div class="small_slide_info_container">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Rather than toggling I'd try explictly coding a `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` on `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events. Possibly throw in a call to [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) before each slide so that you don't get lots of animations queued up if the user moves the mouse in and out several times quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this....

```
 $(document).ready(function () 
           {
            $("div.small_info_container").mouseover(function () {  
     $(this).parent().find('div.small_slide_info_container').stop().slideDown("fast");
                }).mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).parent().find('div.small_slide_info_container').stop().slideUp("fast");
            })    
          });​
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/mSWP8/7/

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I implemented your JS...basically on my webpage i have like 10 of these divs called elem. However it only seems to work on a few of them :S which I have no idea why. The divs dont seem to get stuck but just some elements dont work at all and some show a fraction of the div sliding up :S

Comment: Hey I removed the stop() and it seems to have fixed the suck problem and it shows on all elements! thanks for the help!